# Manim - Aligning terms in equation

Tags: latex, manim

I have a simple manim scene that solves the equation 2x-3=-7. I would like to keep the 2x aligned vertically between each step (as the equals sign has been aligned). Can this be done?

```
class BasicEquationsSimple(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        equation0 = TexMobject("2x - 3", "=", "{-7}")
        equation1 = TexMobject("2x", "=", "{-4}").next_to(equation0, DOWN)
        equation2 = TexMobject("x", "=", "{-2}").next_to(equation1, DOWN)

        eq0 = equation0.get_part_by_tex('=')
        eq1 = equation1.get_part_by_tex('=').align_to(eq0, LEFT)
        eq2 = equation2.get_part_by_tex('=').align_to(eq1, LEFT)

        equation0.get_part_by_tex('2x - 3').next_to(eq0, LEFT)
        equation0.get_part_by_tex('{-7}').next_to(eq0, RIGHT)
        equation1.get_part_by_tex('2x').next_to(eq1,LEFT)
        equation1.get_part_by_tex('{-4}').next_to(eq1, RIGHT)
        equation2.get_part_by_tex('x').next_to(eq2, LEFT)
        equation2.get_part_by_tex('{-2}').next_to(eq2, RIGHT)

        self.play(Write(equation0,run_time=3))
        self.play(Write(equation1))
        self.play(Write(equation2))
```

[image: Manim scene]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I ended up going with.

```
eq = 
[
[TexMobject("{2x}"),TexMobject("{-}"),TexMobject("{4}"),TexMobject("{=}"),TexMobject("{-3}")],
[TexMobject("{2x}"),"","",TexMobject("{=}"),TexMobject("{1}")],
[TexMobject("{x}"),"","",TexMobject("{=}"),TexMobject("{1 \\over 2}")]
]

lines = len(eq)
rails = len(eq[1])

for i in range(lines):
   for j in range(rails):
      if(eq[i][j] != ""):
         eq[i][j].move_to([j-0.5*rails+0.5,-i+0.5*lines-0.5,0])
```

Comment: This has issues with x^2 and y terms due to the fact that heights vary among terms (eg 1,x, x^2 have different heights) and manim positions things by the centre of the bounding box for a term/

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the best solution but it works...

```
from manimlib.imports import *

class BasicEquationsSimple(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        equation0 = TexMobject("2x - 3", "=", "{-7}")
        equation1 = TexMobject("2x", "=", "{-4}").next_to(equation0, DOWN)
        equation2 = TexMobject("x", "=", "{-2}").next_to(equation1, DOWN)

        eq0 = equation0.get_part_by_tex('=')
        eq1 = equation1.get_part_by_tex('=').align_to(eq0, LEFT)
        eq2 = equation2.get_part_by_tex('=').align_to(eq1, LEFT)

        equation0.get_part_by_tex('2x - 3').next_to(eq0, LEFT)
        equation0.get_part_by_tex('{-7}').next_to(eq0, RIGHT)
        equation1.get_part_by_tex('2x').next_to(eq1, LEFT)
        equation1.get_part_by_tex('{-4}').next_to(eq1, RIGHT)
        equation2.get_part_by_tex('x').next_to(eq2, LEFT)
        equation2.get_part_by_tex('{-2}').next_to(eq2, RIGHT)

        equation1.get_part_by_tex('2x').move_to((1.15*LEFT)+(0.6*DOWN))
        equation2.get_part_by_tex('x').move_to((1.05*LEFT)+(1.2*DOWN))

        self.play(Write(equation0,run_time=3))
        self.play(Write(equation1))
        self.play(Write(equation2))
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! Now that I understand Manim a bit better I've created an array of TexMobjects. I have placed each term at a point on a coordinate grid and this keeps everything aligned. I know these equations are basic but, for highschool students, I think keeping things aligned helps to add clarity to the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the community edition, there is another simpler way to do this (using the [align function](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/tutorials/using_text.html?highlight=align#aligning-formulae)):

```py
class BasicEquationsSimple(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        eqns = MathTex(r"2x - 3 & = -7 \\ 2x & = -4 \\ x & = -2")
        self.play(Write(eqns))
```

Perhaps this also works with the Cairo and OpenGL versions (replace `MathTex` with `TexMobject`)...

Comment: Your answer doesn't align on `x` though, the `&` symbol is at the wrong location.

Comment: True - I missed that point. I am aligning on =. I believe the pattern is clear for following whatever you want to align on. I will take another look at it later to see if you can align more than one item.

Comment: yes, your approach works. Thanks! When I try to use multiple `&`, the spacing looks weird